# Convert data feed to Json in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, jackson

I have a file with data as below, which is basically department employee count.
Dept a has 2 sub departments b and c with employees 10 and 30 respectively. Dept d has just one sub dept e with 50 employees. But Dept d has over all 90 (50 + 40 others who are not part of sub dept e but in dept d )

```
[a , b] = 10
[a , c] = 30
[d , e] = 50
[d] = 40
```

I need to convert the above to the below Json (format) for an UI component. What's the best logic for this using objectMapper maybe or anything in Java.

```
{
 "deptname"="CompName",
 "count" = 130,
 "depts" = [
           {
              "deptname"="a",
              "count" = 40,
              "depts" = [
                         {
                            "deptname"="b",
                             "count" = 10
                         },
                         {
                             "deptname"="c",
                             "count" = 30
                         }
                        ]
           },
           {
               "deptname"="d",
                "count" = 90,
                "depts" = [
                            {
                              "deptname"="e",
                              "count" = 50
                            }
                          ]
            }
          ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a parser and data model of your data feed?

Comment: *"What's the best logic"* A `Department` class and a `Map<String, Department>` for storing the data in memory, line-reading and regex for reading the file, and a JSON library of your choice for generating the JSON.

Comment: @AlexRudenko By parser you mean something like jackson ObjectMapper in java? I am using that. for parsing my json now. And I am not using and model. The UI component needs the data in that format

Comment: @Andreas  The approach of doing Map<Sting, Department> might not be very straight forward. Departments contain Department with employee counts at both levels

Comment: @samissac So? I don't see the problem. Round one you build the `Map<String, Department>` and add child departments to their parent. Round two you add up the totals. Or you skip round two and have the `getTotal()` do it for you.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks . Your suggestion also helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model for JSON serialization may look like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

public class Dept {
    private String deptname;
    private int count = 0;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<Dept> depts = null;

    public String getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }
    public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count + countSubdeps();
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public List<Dept> getDepts() {
        return depts;
    }
    public void setDepts(List<Dept> depts) {
        this.depts = depts;
    }

    public void addSubDept(Dept dept) {
        if (this.depts == null) {
            this.depts = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.depts.add(dept);
    }

    private int countSubdeps() {
        if (null == depts || depts.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        return depts.stream().mapToInt(d -> d.getCount()).sum();
    }
}
```

and you can serialize it to JSON using ObjectMapper.

**Update** Sample parser implementation (without recursion):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dept root = new Dept();
    root.setDeptname("CompName");

    String src = "[a , b] = 10\n" + 
        "[a , c] = 30\n" + 
        "[d , e] = 50\n" + 
        "[d] = 40";
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(src.split("\n"));
    root.setDepts(parseDepts(lines));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root));
}

private static String reg = "^\\[\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(,\\s*(\\w+)\\s*)?\\]\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)\\s*$";
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);

private static List<Dept> parseDepts(List<String> lines) {
    if (null == lines || lines.isEmpty())
        return null;
    Map<String, Dept> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String entry : lines) {
        Matcher match = p.matcher(entry);
        if (match.matches()) {
            String dep = match.group(1);
            String subdep = match.group(3);
            int count = Integer.parseInt(match.group(4));

            Dept dept = map.getOrDefault(dep, new Dept());
            dept.setDeptname(dep);
            if (subdep != null) {
                Dept sub = new Dept();
                sub.setDeptname(subdep);
                sub.setCount(count);
                dept.addSubDept(sub);
            } else {
                dept.setCount(count);
            }
            map.put(dep, dept);
        }
    }
    return map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Yes that model would be good to store . I am going to try out the model you provided to see if i can think of parsing the input file

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is what I wanted. Below is the output from your program. Accepting this as the answer {
  "deptname" : "CompName",
  "count" : 130,
  "depts" : [ {
    "deptname" : "a",
    "count" : 40,
    "depts" : [ {
      "deptname" : "b",
      "count" : 10
    }, {
      "deptname" : "c",
      "count" : 30
    } ]
  }, {
    "deptname" : "d",
    "count" : 90,
    "depts" : [ {
      "deptname" : "e",
      "count" : 50
    } ]
  } ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but , in my case the dept name repeated.

```
[a , b] = 10
[a , c] = 30
[a , c] = 20
[d , e] = 50
[d] = 40
[d] = 40
```

I need to add [a, c] = 30 and [a ,c] =20 to make it  50 , (instead of 30)
.[d] should be 130  , How can I get it modified as below ?

```
`"depts" = [
       {
          "deptname"="a",
          "count" = 40,
          "depts" = [
                     {
                        "deptname"="b",
                         "count" = 10
                     },
                     {
                         "deptname"="c",
                         "count" = 50
                     }
                     ]
        },
       {
           "deptname"="d",
            "count" = 130,
            "depts" = [
                        {
                          "deptname"="e",
                          "count" = 80
                        }
                      ]
        }
      ]
```

} 
`